# Let $f$ be continuous in $[a,b)$ with no mimimum at all open interval and tend to infinity. Prove it is strictly increasing.

Tags: real-analysis, continuity, solution-verification

[image]

I would like to check if my logic is correct. 
If $f$ is already monotonic, I can show that is strictly increasing by taking 2 points $f(x_1) = f(x_2)$ then $f((x_1,x_2))$  would be same everywhere so it would have a minimum. (I am not sure whether it is rigorous enough). 
But, in order to show that it must be increasing, I must show that $f(x_1) > f(x_2)$ if $x_1<x_2$ implies a minimum. Intuitively, I can take $(x_1,x_3)$ such that $f(x_1) >f(x_2)$ and $f(x_3)>f(x_2) $ and $x_1<x_2<x_3$ which $x_3$ always exist because $f(x)$ tends to infinity. Then, since $f([x_1,x_3])$ has a minimum due to compactness and continuity, which is neither $f(x_1)$ nor $f(x_3)$ then $f((x_1,x_3))$ has a minimum, which contradicts.

Answer (score 1):

Your argument is correct.

I would correct only one minor thing:

> If $f$ is already monotonic, I can show that is strictly increasing by taking 2 points $f(x_1)=f(x_2)$ then $f((x_1,x_2))$ would be same everywhere so it would have a minimum. (I am not sure whether it is rigorous enough).

I don't know what $f((x_1,x_2))$ means. To be precise, in this case $f$ doesn't have to constant everywhere, but constant on $[x_1,x_2]$. And this is enough, since we can conclude it has a minimum on this interval.

---

And let me remark that the second part of your argument can be altered so that it shows strict monotonicity. That is, you pick $x_1<x_2$ satisfying $f(x_1) \ge f(x_2)$, then choose $x_3>x_2$ satisfying $f(x_3) \ge f(x_2)$ as well (thanks to the infinite limit). As before, there's a minimum on $[x_1,x_3]$. This time, it **could** be $f(x_1)$ or $f(x_3)$, but in that scenario it would also be $f(x_2)$. Contradiction.